# Why is this Kubernetes PV/PVC setup not working?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am reading Core Kubernetes by Vyas and Love. This is the YAML file from page 141, section 7.3.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dynamic1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100k
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /shared
        name: shared
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www
        name: dynamic1
      - mountPath: /shared
        name: shared
  volumes:
  - name: dynamic1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dynamic1
  - name: shared
    emptyDir: {}
```

I run `kubectl create` on this file, and then `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`.  It shows the `nginx` pod is having status `CrashLoopBackOff`.  Using `kubectl describe pods nginx` shows:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  105s                default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
Normal   Scheduled         104s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to minikube
Normal   Pulling           101s                kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
Normal   Pulled            101s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 2.289652482s
Normal   Pulled            99s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 2.219896558s
Normal   Created           98s                 kubelet            Created container nginx
Normal   Started           98s                 kubelet            Started container nginx
Normal   Pulled            96s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 2.23260066s
Normal   Pulled            78s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 2.245476487s
Normal   Pulling           49s (x4 over 103s)  kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
Normal   Created           47s (x4 over 101s)  kubelet            Created container busybox
Normal   Pulled            47s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 2.287877562s
Warning  BackOff           46s (x5 over 95s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
Normal   Started           46s (x4 over 101s)  kubelet            Started container busybox
```

Running `kubectl logs nginx nginx` shows:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.2
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
2022/12/08 14:37:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
```

Running `kubectl logs nginx busybox` shows nothing.  I then comment out the `busybox` container inside the `nginx` pod, it works fine.  When I comment out the 'nginx' container inside the `nginx` pod, it runs into the error again.  I wonder why this container is causing this problem?  Any insight is appreciated.

Addendum:

Running `kubectl get sc` shows:

```
NAME                 PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  35h
```

Running `kubectl get event` shows:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON    OBJECT      MESSAGE
2m12s       Warning   BackOff   pod/nginx   Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: try `kubectl get event` to see if there are any errors with scheduling

Comment: Please see the addendum for additional info.

Comment: Probably this url will answer your question:
[busy box is not used for endless loop](https://serverfault.com/questions/1098192/cant-start-busybox-pod)

Comment: Probably this url will answer your question: [busybox is not a server. It does not start the endless "listen for input" loop](https://serverfault.com/questions/1098192/cant-start-busybox-pod)

Answer (score 2):

Googling around, I find this [busybox.yaml](https://github.com/josedom24/kubernetes/blob/master/ejemplos/busybox/busybox.yaml) file which has the `sleep` command.  I add that to the `busybox` container as follows:

```
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /shared
        name: shared
```

Now the yaml file works.  I guess this is related to Sreepada Jayanthi's answer.  This Reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/jp2ia9/crashloopbackoff_status_using_busybox_images/) also explains the details.